# Executing multiple SELECT queries in postgreSQL simultaneously

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, postgresql-14

I'm trying to execute multiple postgreSQL SELECT queries at once.

i.e:

```
"SELECT * FROM table1; SELECT * from table2;"
```

Preferably I'd then be able to fetch the results of first

```
"SELECT * FROM table1;"
```

and then the results of

```
SELECT * from table2;"
```

But what ends up happening is I'll only get the results for `table2` and not the results for `table1` I got the suggestion to run `cursor.fetchall()` followed by `cursor.nextset()` but `cursor.nextset()` doesn't seem to be available in the `psycopg2` package, only in the `psycopg` package which I'm unable to install

does anyone know how to solve this?

Eventually I'll be doing 10-15 queries at a time so I'd save considerable amounts of time if I could simple execute all the queries at once instead of doing them concurrently

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that, the purpose is to select both tables with join, full outer allows you to get every fields even they're null.

1=0 condition is just to don't join rows

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 a
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 b ON 1=0
```

Comment: Hmm ok, I have another case where I want to execute these queries:

`SELECT max(value) from table1 WHERE time > x and time < y;`
`SELECT min(value) from table2 WHERE time > x and time < y;`

is there any way to do these using JOIN ?

Comment: Then you can do a union between both when you have only one column for each request or do a nested request like : SELECT (SELECT max(value) from table1 WHERE time > x and time < y) (SELECT min(value) from table2 WHERE time > x and time < y)
try something like that and tel me if it worked

Comment: it didnt work sadly